# Long Press on BottomNavigationBarItem

Tags: flutter

Is there any way to handle long press on the items of BottomNavigationBar in Flutter?

I see "onTap" event handler, but nothing else and I also cannot wrap the Items into GestureDetector.

I can wrap the whole BottomNavigationBar section into the GestureDetector but in this case it's not possible to realize which Item was pressed :-/

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

After couple of days I finally understood how to realize it: you just need (as almost always) wrap Icon and Text of you bottom navigation bar items into GestureDetector widget and it works :)

The snippet would be:

```
new BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: GestureDetector(
            onLongPress: (){print("long tap icon");
            setState(() {
              _resetSct(context, i);
            });
            },
            child: new Image.memory([skiped])), //Icon(Icons.looks_one),//photos[0].icon,
        title: GestureDetector(
            onLongPress: (){print("long tap title");
            setState(() {
              //do stuff
            });
            },
            child: Text([skipped]))
```

Answer (score 0):

With Flutter I recommend you to create your custom Bottom Navigation Bar as it is very easy to do.

**Note:** There is no way to do what you want using the default BottomNaivgationBarItem.

Comment: ok, thanks for tip, I thought, it's was not possible. Any link to the example with custom solution?

Answer (score -3):

You need also to add enableFeedback as true and wrap your icon with GestureDetector

```
BottomNavigationBar(
      enableFeedback: true,
```

This is works for me.